# Load cms content before react component mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, gatsby

I want to import my post from ButterCMS to React, but I don't know how to deal with the async problem.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Butter from "buttercms"

import gradient from "../../images/TealLove.jpg"

export default () => {
  const butter = Butter("API_KEY")
  const [post, setPost] = useState()

  butter.post.list({ page: 1, page_size: 10 }).then(function(response) {
    setPost(response.data.data[0])
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className={"section"}>
        <div className={"container"}>
          <div className={"first-post"}>
            <figure className={"image"}>
              <img src={gradient} alt=""></img>
            </figure>

            <div className={"first-post-title"}>
              <h2>
                {post.title.length > 20
                  ? post.title.slice(0, 85) + " ..."
                  : post.title}
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Every time I run this, the error `post is undefined` will show up.
How can I render the element only after the post has been defined?

Comment: may be the **useEffect** hook could solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a check before rendering and render a fallback loading indicator..

```
return (
    post ?
      <div className={"section"}>
        <div className={"container"}>
          <div className={"first-post"}>
            <div className={"first-post-title"}>
              <h2>
                {post.title.length > 20
                  ? post.title.slice(0, 85) + " ..."
                  : post.title}
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  : "loading..."
  )
```

The above code loads post only if it is defined else returns "loading".

Inside the `useEffect` hook you can call the API and set the state.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch("URL")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setPost(json));
  }, [])
```

Once the API call is complete, the state changes and the component re-renders with post data.

An example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-htofev